Opening pre-defined library in MPLAB X IDE
Recently I downloaded a firmware from microchip that handles BLDC motor control. The project is entitled "KICK_SCOOTER" and uses dsPIC33 as controller. Trying to understand how the program works and going through the header files and source files,The main program includes the folowing header files:
#include "FOC.h"

My objective is to understand how FOC (Field Oriented Control) algorithm is implemented in a real time controller (dsPIC33). When I open this header file, I find some function that are not defined eleswhere in the whole project. But there is a library included in that project with two extensions (Kick_scooter.X.a  and libx2cscope-33ck-elf.a). I expect these functions are emebedded in these two files(libraries).
My question is how can I open the library in order to extract and handle the embedded functions of that library?

You can't. A ".a" file is a precompile library file - the original C source code is not included.

Try to use "simple FOC community"
there you can find usefull knowledge about it

You can find some dsPIC33 foc.c, foc.h files from here.
I'm not sure they match the program you have, however.

Another source is maybe the MCC. Habe a look here MCC. Have a look for the motor bench development suite.
